# Can't install Ubuntu on unallocated space (Lenovo with Windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Hello I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my laptop that already has Windows 10 Home edition as it's main OS. I've read that it's possible to create a dual boot system with both Windows and Ubuntu and so I looked for some guides online for help on the topic and I started:

1. I created an ISO image in my USB stick with the ubuntu installer using rufus.
2. I created an unallocated space using the partitioning app that Windows has.
3. I rebooted my computer and selected my USB as the way to boot.
4. I chose the option to Try Ubuntu without installing it.

Then everything works fine, I get to the desktop page of Ubuntu and the installer on it, i double click it and I choose English as the option to install and pick the normal installation but when I get to the part to choose where I want to install Ubuntu it's just an empty list and the unallocated space is nowhere to be found.

I'm really new to using Ubuntu and I'd appreciate any help with this, ask me if I need to give more detailed information I will provide it.

Thanks.

[image: Gparted "screenshot"]

Edit: I've included a link to a photo of my screen when I ran Gparted.

Comment: Most likely disk type is Dynamic. Check that in Windows.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for your quick reply, I just checked that and my disk is shown as Basic.

Comment: Run gparted and post the screen to your question.

Comment: could it be the fast startup thing? try to shutdown Windows with `shutdown /P`

Comment: @Pilot6 hi, I used Gparted and took a screenshot but I can't find where it is saved. The program says that it was saved to home/user but I don't know where that is (I installed Gparted on a USB stick and ran it from there). I'll take a photo with my phone and post it.

Comment: @cmak.fr hello I already disabled the fast startup setting.

Comment: @Pilot6 I posted the picture I mentioned before thanks.

Comment: Is your disk controller set to RAID in the BIOS? ps: your gparted screenshot is of the wrong disk.

Comment: @heynnema hi I just checked the BIOS and there's an option that says: SATA controller mode [RAID]. Do you need a picture of this? (thanks for replying to my post)

Comment: That's your problem. Give me a few minutes to write an answer that will help fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a single SSD/HDD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD/HDD until you switch your disk controller setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

Below, you'll find two different ways to solve this problem.

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand `Storage Controllers` and identify the `Intel SATA RAID Controller`
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`
- Select `Microsoft` as manufacturer
- Select `Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller` as model #
- Accept that `Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible`
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:

  - Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
  - Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`

  - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`

  - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer I'll give you an update when I try one of the choices!

Comment: Thank you! I've just concluded with the Ubuntu installation after many hours of searching about my issue and nobody ever mentions the AHCI mode. I picked the first choice and did a backup of my WIndows and it was a good idea to do that because after restarting my PC it couldn't boot WIndows normally so I had to do a system recovery, then I proceeded with the Ubuntu installation, now my drive appeared in the list and also the unallocated partition. I could finally install Ubuntu. Thank you so much!